# Table funtion Vs Scripted Calculation Views in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

As we all know that SAP has suggested to use Table function instead of Scripted calculation views.

I tried to search for the reason but could not find much.

I was told that they are faster than scripted views but I never found it faster in my scenarios.

Can anyone tell me what is the reason to use table function instead of scripted views in hana.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SAP has set scripted calculation views to obsolete, after the option was added that table functions can be used in graphical calculation views. Also a migration way is provided 
 [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/fc5ace7a367c434190a8047881f92ed8/2.0.03/en-US/c29542be5fc745ba99d3fcd89d3e1137.html)

Performance was not the reason, because if you have two times the same implementation (scripted view or calc. view using just a table function with the same coding than the scripted view), there will be real difference.

The reason was basically just some house-keeping to not have twice basically the same thing.